# jQuery get divs html from inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following html:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get all the divs html from within the `div` with `id="parent"`. After that build an array and push each html to it.

Basically I need to get this:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

rather then this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

And the jQuery code:

```
var val = [];

$.each($('#parent'), function (i, left) {
    $('div', left).each(function () {

        var data = $(this).html();
        val.push(data);

    });
});

alert(JSON.stringify(val));
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uabL649m/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/), which will return an array of the children `div` elements.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/a5uh6dex/)

```
var divs = $('#parent div').map(function () {
    return this;
}).get();
```

---

You don't need to use jQuery for this, though. Here is a plain JS option which returns the same results:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vt1t7qLs/)

```
var divs = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#parent div'), function (el) {
    return el;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count=$('#parent > div').length;
for(i=0;i<count;i++){

console.log($('#parent > div')[i].outerHTML);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uabL649m/2/

Answer (score 0):

try [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), like below. Demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/e6qxxaew/)

```
var arr = [];
$("#parent > div").each(function() {
    arr.push(this.outerHTML);
});
console.log ( JSON.stringify(arr ) );
```